# Will spaceX crewed boosters have a self-destruct mechanism?

Tags: spacex, spacex-starship, spacex-super-heavy, self-destruct

SpaceX's most recent launch went awry and they [triggered the self-destruct](https://Why%20was%20Space%20X%27s%20Starship%20blown%20up?). Crewed missions have a [launch escape system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launch_escape_system) which is a high-thrust rocket that can get the capsule clear of the main rocket body in emergencies.

After the launch-escape, self-destructing the crippled rocket would reduce downrange threats to the ground. But for every safety feature you must consider what happens if it is *accidentally* activated. So presumably it's not worth the risk to include a detonate-booster feature on crewed missions?

Comment: I wonder what that red flashing light is……

Comment: The Starship is not planned to have a crew escape system. https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46079/6944

Comment: Or the starship's engines are themselves the escape system, if you want to look at it that way.

Comment: related: [Will a computer be allowed to "self-destruct" astronauts (or passengers)?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20620/12102)

Comment: Given the severity of the self-destruct, it'll be designed to prevent accidental triggers. We have been able to avoid killing ourselves even though we have made enough nuclear bombs to destroy the planet multiple times over.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Every crewed launch vehicle so far has had a self-destruct feature.  I see no reason why SpaceX's Super Heavy will be any different.  The same launch escape system that carries the crew away from a crippled rocket can carry it away from one where the self-destruct system has accidentally activated.

Comment: A crippled rocket which is out of control or at risk of explosion or other malfunction most of the time gives the capsule some time to escape. But doesn't the self-destruct cause a fuel-oxidizer explosion "instantly"? If there is i.e. an electrical short that energizes the wires that detonate the perforation charges there will be no time to get out of the blast radius?

Comment: @KevinKostlan, a crippled rocket is also one that is [breaking up because of a rapid spin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-003), or one where [the first stage is exploding from a fire in the engine section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N1_(rocket)#Fourth_failure,_serial_7L).  The self-destruct is no more violent than this: it ruptures the fuel tanks, but since the fuel and oxidizer aren't mixed, the result is more of a rapid fire than a fuel-air explosion.

Comment: Starship will not have a crew escape system https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46079/6944

Comment: The problem with such statements is that Starship is *both* the crew vehicle *and* (part of) the launch vehicle. Like the STS Orbiter, and that one did *not* have an FTS as far as I know.

Comment: @JörgWMittag the Shuttle itself may not have but I think the stack in general did (specifically the SRBs).

Comment: Every US crewed launch vehicle. I'm not sure that non-US ones have also had a flight termination system...

Comment: @fyrepenguin, the SRBs had a destruct system on every launch, while the External Tank had one up through STS-78.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Look at the Challenger catastrophe.  Watch the boosters after things go wrong--they receive and honor a destruct command.  (Note that most of the video out there focuses on the main explosion and doesn't show this.  You need to find one that shows the boosters.)

Comment: @LorenPechtel: The SRBs are not the Orbiter.